# Django Form Wizard with Jquery steps

Tags: jquery, django, django-formwizard, jquery-steps

How would one get Django forms wizard to work with Jquery steps (http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#tabs)? Would I have to manually write out the html instead of using Django form? Sorry I know this a very vague and general question but I just need some ideas to attack this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make tabs with absolute link, without jquery, that is easy solution.
On every step(new page) you can make new form..

Or other solution, to make 1 form, then on each tab, generate only fields that you need for that tab, manually..